# MATLAB Parallel Computing Toolbox - Parallelization vs GPU?

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, matlab

I'm working with someone who has some MATLAB code that they want to be sped up. They are currently trying to convert all of this code into CUDA to get it to run on a CPU. I think it would be faster to use MATLAB's parallel computing toolbox to speed this up, and run it on a cluster that has MATLAB's Distributed Computing Toolbox, allowing me to run this across several different worker nodes. Now, as part of the parallel computing toolbox, you can use [things like GPUArray](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html). However, I'm confused as to how this would work. Are using things like parfor (parallelization) and gpuarray (gpu programming) compatible with each other? Can I use both? Can something be split across different worker nodes (parallelization) while also making use of whatever GPUs are available on each worker?

They think its still worth exploring the time it takes to convert all of your matlab code to cuda code to run on a machine with multiple GPUs...but I think the right approach would be to use the features already built into MATLAB.

Any help, advice, direction would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You might consider trying Jacket for this instead of gpuArrays.  I've not heard of anyone happy with the performance of gpuArrays, for these reasons:  http://accelereyes.com/compare

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use parfor, you are effectively dividing your for loop into tasks, with one task per loop iteration, and splitting up those tasks to be computed in parallel by several workers where each worker can be thought of as a MATLAB session without an interactive GUI. You configure your cluster to run a specified number of workers on each node of the cluster (generally, you would choose to run a number of workers equal to the number of available processor cores on that node).

On the other hand, gpuarray indicates to MATLAB that you want to make a matrix available for processing by the GPU. Underneath the hood, MATLAB is marshalling the data from main memory to the graphics board's internal memory. Certain MATLAB functions (there's a list of them in the documentation) can operate on gpuarrays and the computation happens on the GPU.

The key differences between the two techniques are that parfor computations happen on the CPUs of nodes of the cluster with direct access to main memory. CPU cores typically have a high clock rate, but there are typically fewer of them in a CPU cluster than there are GPU cores. Individually, GPU cores are slower than a typical CPU core and their use requires that data be transferred from main memory to video memory and back again, but there are many more of them in a cluster. As far as I know, hybrid approaches are supposed to be possible, in which you have a cluster of PCs and each PC has one or more Nvidia Tesla boards and you use both parfor loops and gpuarrays. However, I haven't had occasion to try this yet.

Answer (score 5):

If you are mainly interested in simulations, GPU processing is the perfect choice. However, if you want to analyse (big) data, go with Parallization. The reason for this is, that GPU processing is only faster than cpu processing if you don't have to copy data back and forth. In case of a simulation, you can generate most of the data on the GPU and only need to copy the result back. If you try to work with bigger data on the GPU you will very often run into out of memory problems. 
Parallization is great if you have big data structures and more than 2 cores in your computer CPU.

Answer (score -2):

If you write it in CUDA it is guaranteed to run in parallel at the chip-level versus going with MATLAB's best guess for a non-parallel architecture and your best effort to get it to run in parallel.

Kind of like drinking fresh mountain water run-off versus buying filtered water.  Go with the purist solution.